# Approach - 32bit versus having a try-catch, together with iSeries ODBC driver

Tags: c#, performance, odbc, try-catch, 32bit-64bit

I am in doubt of what to choose, i hope to get your perspectives, and therefore, the answer would be to whom gives the most constructive feedback (now you know what i hope to get)

**The situation.**
I have this dll that i use in many different projects in my company's websites,
its main use is being some kind of data wrapper, i specify some parameters, then it chooses the correct connection string and runs a query against some database.
So its main role is getting data back from different databases in a uniform way, that i then process later.

**Trouble started raining down on me.**
this dll is using odbc drivers to get its data, 
one of these is a 64bit driver called "iSeries Access ODBC Driver"
this driver has this specific problem, if i try to get its datatype it will result in a overflow in a few cases

**Temporary solution**
So i made this hot-fix, using a try-catch to detect the problematic columns, if the catch block is hit i set the datatype to string. The ODBC has no problem getting the data, i just cant detect if the data is decimal or character without using try-catch....
that is, in the 64bit version of the driver, the 32bit version works just fine.

**My options**

1. Use the try-catch and stay in 64bit world
2. Skip the try-catch and stay in the 32bit world
3. Get all the data as string, then code some "decimal detection" code to evaluate

**Little note**
I just upgraded the driver, the old version was even worse, now i have some functionality at least, it was from like 2005, the new one also performs much better, i have also made this library in C# and am using .net 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the number of exceptions you would get... Exceptions in .NET are fairly slow if too many are throwed. If it's one/minute there isn't any problem... Otherwise...

The `Get all the data as string, then code some "decimal detection" code to evaluate` is probably the better one. At least then you can use `decimal.TryParse`.

Comment: In some code, i would get none, but some reports (typical the larger ones) i will get thousands,

Comment: @No-Chip Thousand is a thousand too much :-) The third option, then :-) :-)

Comment: Got some trouble if a cell seems like the data is decimal, but really is just string numbers with some dots and commas, (this is danish so i need to convert all decimal dots to commas) converting everything to string gives me some strange results due to the implicit language number conversion... i might not want to use the 3. option just yet, so it now comes down to, should i go with the 32 bit option versus performance in try catch in 64 bit option :)

Comment: @No-Chip You should use var culture = new CultureInfo("da-DK", false); decimal dec; bool success = decimal.TryParse("Mystring", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, culture, out dec)` and not simply replace `.` with `,`.

Comment: I'm not replacing :) sorry if i gave you that idea, i am using odbc.getstring or odbc.getdecimal (or the others) to get the data out, this uses the default culture, (i checked it is "da-DK") so this works fine, but thanks for your code, that might just get the data out with decimal detection, i'll test on Monday! i might need to explain the situation in more detail. Thanks for your consistent help